# Unable to write a file while using Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am unable to create and then write a file in Tomcat. The file gets created if I run the java program (only the writing piece of code) as a **Java application**, but fails in Tomcat.

there is no error message. The file is simply not created at all!

Please suggest if I am missing something here:

```
//code inside the servlet
public void setData(HttpServletRequest request){
    name=request.getParameter("name");
    address=request.getParameter("address");


    BufferedWriter dataOut;
    try {
        System.out.println("Wrinting file...");
        dataOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.txt", true));




        dataOut.write("name:");
        dataOut.flush();

        dataOut.write("address");
        dataOut.flush();

        dataOut.write("\n");
        dataOut.flush();

        dataOut.close();
        System.out.println("File write complete!");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Actually the file gets created, but where are you looking for it?

Comment: as you didn't specify the full path of the file, it will be created in the current context of tomcat. Specify the full path example
     
       dataOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("d:\\data.txt", true));

check the D:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the file really is created without problems.

You may actually be missing **where** it is saved.

Change this line:

```
System.out.println("File write complete!");
```

To:

```
System.out.println("File write complete! Saved to: "+new File("data.txt").getAbsolutePath());
```

And you may solve the mistery.

Answer (score 3):

The file is being created, but it is using a relative path. It will be created *relative* to the execution location, which on Tomcat will not be where you're used to it being.

Use an absolute path or print its location.

Comment: thanks!!! i got this message..File write complete! Saved to: /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/data.txt     how do i save it to Web-Content folder?

Comment: how do i save it to web-content folder?

Comment: Rather than the relative path "data.txt", use an absolute path: "/Users/path/to/web-content/data.txt", or use a relative path that will place it where you want it (I don't know where the folder you want is in relation to where the file is now): "../../../path/to/web-content/data.txt"